# Start a job in SQL SERVER after another job succeeds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to run a procedure in MSSQL based on result of some step in other job.

What I want to achieve:
I want to run a specific procedure after LOAD of data. I dont want to set job start time only at specific time but I want to condition run also on success of other step in other job. But I want tu run a job only if some step in other job was successful. And I want to run it at specific time.

The catch is that this procedure is in other JOB. These two procedures are not in the same JOB.

Is it possible to make a condition like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, may be but you need to explain more on what other job? what's you are trying to achieve?

Comment: One job step runs *ONLY* if the previous step succeeds. What you describe is the default behavior. You can change this in the previous step's failure action. Are you asking how to call one job from another?

Comment: If you google for `T-SQL run job` you'll see that you can use `sp_start_job` in a job step, eg `EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Weekly Sales Data Backup' `. Add this as the last step of the previous job

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I found. Do you think I can put it as well into step of the job? Sorry, I am new to MS SQL.

Comment: You can put this as the last step of the previous job

Comment: Well, the thing is - when I do it like this, I will run the job at right after the previous step but I need job to run at specific time. Can I edit it also?